# RestController Spring, como limitar o numero de requisições!

Tags: java, api, spring, restful

Caros amigos, tenho uma *API Rest* com o `RestController` do Spring, ela recebe centenas de posts simultâneos, e a cada postagem, eu preciso fazer consultas e armazenar dados no banco de dados. P problema é que isso está gerando um processamento absurdo na máquina!

Existe alguma forma que limitar o numero de posts ou colocar alguns em espera?

Answer (score 1):

Talvez, se você implementar uma solução assíncrona o problema seja resolvido. Confira este [material](http://blog.caelum.com.br/invocando-metodos-assincronos-com-spring/).
Com uma implementação assíncrona, o seu sistema não será travado ao receber uma requisição que demande um processamento mais longo.
Espero que tenha-o ajudado.